# Min and Max value Reactstrap Input Type Date (Calendar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, calendar, reactstrap

I'm trying to add a Calendar to my website that makes an appoinment and I need to make it, obviously, from today to the future. How can I do that with the Reactstrap component? Can't find on docs.

Importing the Calendar:

```
import { Input } from "reactstrap";

    <Input
      type="time"
      className="form-control"
      id="time-start-input"
      value={startTime}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setTime(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
```

How can I put a minValue to receive dates just after that date?
For example:

```
minValue={today}
```

And then, disable the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the doc of Reactstrap Datepicker, you can use the minDate :
https://reactstrap-date-picker.afialapis.com/#mindate

```
<FormGroup>
        <Label>My Date Picker</Label>
        <DatePicker 
           id      = "example-datepicker" 
           minDate={"2016-05-19T12:00:00.000Z"}
        <FormText>Help</FormText>
 </FormGroup>
```